# Proof verification: Baby Rudin Chapter 4 exercise 4

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove:

> $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, $g: X \to Y$ is continuous, $E \subset X$ is dense in $X \implies$ $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$ and $\forall p \in E, g(p) = f(p) \implies g(p) = f(p) \forall p \in X$.

My attempt for proving $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$:

Suppose $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, $g: X \to Y$ is continuous, $E \subset X$ is dense in $X$. Let $f(x) \in f(X)$ for some $x \in X$. Let $f[V_a(x)]$ be an arbitrary neighborhood of $f(x)$.
Since $E$ is dense in $X$, $x$ must be a limit point of $E$, <s>that is</s>  so that, for the neighborhood $V_a(x)$ of $x$, $\exists q \ne x$ such that $q \in E$ and $q \in V_a(x)$. Then, $f(q) \ne f(x)$ is such that $f(q) \in f(E)$ and $f(q) \in f[V_a(x)]$ which shows that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(E)$. Since $f(x)$ was arbitrarily chosen, $f(E)$ is dense in $f(X)$.

My attempt for proving $\forall p \in E, g(p) = f(p) \implies g(p) = f(p) \forall p \in X$:

We prove the contrapositive: suppose $g(p) \ne f(p) \forall p \in X$. Since $E \subset X$, $g(p) \ne f(p) \forall p \in E$ follows immediately.

**My question**: I am sure there is plenty wrong with my proofs (for instance, I never used the continuity of $f$ and $g$). I want to ask how my proofs are incorrect. Please know that I'm not looking for new ways of proving this statement as those can be found on the internet. I'm looking for feedback on my proofs, and ways of improving them. Thanks!

Comment: the negation of "for all $p\in X, g(p)=f(p)$" is not "for all $p\in X, g(p)\ne f(p)$" but rather "for *some* $p\in X, g(p)\ne f(p)$"

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That makes sense, thanks! Now I know why the second part of the proof is incorrect.

Comment: After "$x$ must be a limit point of $E$" you need "for every neighborhood $V_a(x)$" instead of what you have which would only apply for the single neighborhood previously mentioned.

Comment: @Peter I mention $V_a(x)$ specifically as that is the only neighborhood of $x$ that I will need for the rest of the proof. I know that the result holds for any neighborhood of $x$, but I don't require that to complete the proof.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson, "that is" means you are explaining what the limit point is. If you are using the fact to apply to the specific neighbourhood you should say something like "and so" instead of "that is".

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: You took $V_a(x)$ to be a nbhd of $f(x)$, not of $x$, but thereafter you treated it as a nbhd of $x$. You do need to start with an open nbhd of $f(x)$, say $V$, since you’re trying to prove that $f(x)$ is in the closure of $f[E]$, but then you need to work with $f^{-1}[V]$, an open nbhd of $x$>

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Sorry, that was a typo (fixed now). I meant to take $f(V_a(x))$, not $V_a(x)$, as an arbitrary neighborhood of $f(x)$.

Comment: @Peter I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know! I've edited my proof.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: You need to start with an open nbhd of $f(x)$; if you start with an open nbhd $V$ of $x$, there is no guarantee that $f[V]$ is a nbhd of $f(x)$ at all. What you’re trying to show is that every open nbhd of $f(x)$ contains a point of $f[E]$, so you **must** start with an arbitrary open nbhd of $f(x)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If I understand your comment correctly, I think I know where I went wrong. But how is it that if $V$ is some neighborhood of $x$, then $f[V]$ is not a neighborhood of  $f(x)$? Since $x \in X, f(x) \in f(X)$, and doesn't this mean that if $V$ is some neighborhood of $x$, then $f[V]$ must also be a neighborhood of  $f(x)$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: No, it does not. A function $f:X\to Y$ that has the property that $f[U]$ is open in $Y$ whenever $U$ is open in $X$ is called an *open* function. Not every open function is continuous, and not every continuous function is open. For instance, the function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=x$ if $x\ge 0$ is continuous but not open: it sends the open set $(-1,0)$ to the non-open set $\{0\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, that totally resolved my question!

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson: You’re welcome!